# How to change background images using media query without any page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without any page load, I want to change the background image using JavaScript.

```js
const getbg = (bgimg) => {
  if (body.offsetWidth > 780) {
    body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${bgimg[0]})`;
  }
  else if (body.offsetWidth > 780 && body.offsetWidth > 580) {
    body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${bgimg[1]})`;
  }
  else {
    body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${bgimg[2]})`;
  }
};
```

My code is not working perfectly.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation for media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: How is `getbg` used? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Are you using a [`resize` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)? Possible duplicate of [Is there any DOM event listeners to detect change in height of window?](/q/67661359/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use css? like the below. It would still change your bg image without page load.

```
@media(max-width:650px){
 .your-class{
   backround-image: url('image1.jpg');
  }
}

@media(max-width:768px){
 .your-class{
   backround-image: url('image2.jpg');
  }
}
```

Comment: because my data coming from api so i want

Comment: Css should still work even though the data is coming from the API unless I'm missing something. But if you must use JavaScript, please check this link:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp

Answer (score 0):

an advice, use it like upside answer.
don't use any javascript for like this simple css process.

ps : if you work on a js framework, it should have it's own method for this.

```css
/* ================= this is latest way of it. ================= */

background-image: image-set(
    url("small-landscape-750x536.jpg") 750w,
    url("large-landscape-2048x1536.jpg") 20480w);
}

/* ================= this is latest way of it. ================= */
```